# Initializing new array as function argument, in a loop, in Java. Performance

Tags: java, performance, loops, optimization, allocation

Is a new float array allocated for every loop run for the code below?

```
for (Element e : elements) e.colorize( new float[] { 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f } );
```

Is there a performance gain in changing it into the following?

```
float[] color = new float[] { 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f };
for (Element e : elements) e.colorize(color);
```

Comment: it is a performance gain if the number of elements is greater than 1. if there are no elements you would create the array anyways. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There will be a performance gain primarily because there is no longer any memory allocation overhead, and you save tons of space. But the more important part is that you're colorizing the **same** array in the second code example, whereas in the first one you are colorizing a different array every time. If this is what you want, great! If not, then you need to rethink your code.

Comment: I was just wondering if some, for example compile-time, optimization might come into play, because clearly `new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 }` is the same at every loop run. But my thinking was faulty, because there couldn't be any optimization of this sort, as compiler doesn't know what do I wish to do in `colorize()` function with the given array-argument. So it couldn't assume that I don't care about further modifying of `color`, and initialize only one array in both examples...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct. The second one will be more efficient as the array will only be created and initialized once.

Just be aware though that all your colorize calls will be sharing the `float[]` array, so changing the contents of one will change it for all of them. That's unlikely to be a problem in this case but something to be aware of.